# date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given at line 234

Tags: php

I get the following error and I don't know how to solve it..

> date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given at line 234

This is the code:

```
public static function timeLeft($datetime, $out_in_array=false, $html = false) {
      $intervalo = date_diff(date_create(), date_create($datetime)); ----------   LINE 234
        $out = $intervalo->format("%d d, %H h, %i m"); 

        if(!$out_in_array) {
            if($html) {
                return $intervalo->invert ? "<b class='red'>-$out</b>" : "<b class='green'>$out</b>";
            }

            return $intervalo->invert ? "-$out" : $out;
        }

        return [
            'days' => $intervalo->d,
            'hours' => $intervalo->h,
            'minutes' => $intervalo->i,
            'seconds' => $intervalo->s,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `date_create` is an alias of [`DateTime::__construct`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) which returns `false` on error.

Comment: What is $datetime? It's creating an error so you need to look at what is passing a incorrect variable to your function

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because date_diff() must have 2 param.
Your code:

```
$intervalo = date_diff(date_create(), date_create($datetime));
```

date_create() < dont have a param. so you have just second param. correct >date_create($datetime)

How use correctly:

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

Comment: `date_create` could be use without any parameters. [Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-description) since it's an alias of `DateTime::construct`

Comment: If you read the error message *expects parameter **2** to be*. It's parameter 2 that is the problem, not the first.

Comment: Yes, i wrong i didint see well.
Possible format wrong?